# example for passing/sharing data from ListView to EditView controller? (within a UINavigationController layout)

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

Assuming I have a project that is:

- using UINavigationController that has the (a) main screen - list of items, and (b) edit screen for an item
- I have UINavigationController instance held in ApplicationDelegate
- Have two separate UI controllers with NIBs for the List Screen and the Edit Screen (i.e. went ADD UIViewController with a XIB file)
- The list of items is stored in the ListScreen UIViewController (e.g. an NSArray of data objects say)

Question - I'm still not clear on how to trigger/implement the handoff from the ListScreen (after a user clicks on a row) to the Edit/DetailsScreen in terms of how to pass/share the data item, i.e. such that in the EditScreen it could update the data, then when the Edit Controller is pop'ed off the UINavigationController stack, the List Screen would be up-to-date.

Can anyone help out with some comments on how to do this &/or a pointer to some sample code that would demonstrate how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Detail view (I'm gathering from your post that you want to have a detail screen where you can view and edit the item) you'll implement a property for your individual object, whatever it is.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Item *item;
```

Then in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method in the ListController, you'll set that property.

```
detailVC.item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

EDIT: To make sure your listView is up to date when the modal view controller is dismissed, you need to implement a reload in viewWillAppear: in ListViewController. It may be as simple as `[self.tableView reloadData]` if your backing is a simple array.

Comment: thanks DVG - can I clarify (a) the property should be retain & not assign?, (b) if it's retain do I need to mainually release it then prior to swapping back from the Edit to MainList view? (c) it is better to pass the data item from the List to the Edit controller, as opposed to passing a reference to the ListController itself to the EditController?

Comment: You'd need to release it in the controllers dealloc method. You might be able to get away with assign, but I think retain/release is considered the best practice. As to c, passing the view controller as a property wouldn't really accomplish what your looking for and will make your navigation rigid.